# Recommended way to observe, or notify of property changes? Dojo MVC

Tags: javascript, dojo

Given a data model that was created using dojo dmodel library, is there a recommended way to observe for property changes, and set property values in the model?

Am I supposed to go through creating the property objects and use 'observe' to observe for changes on them?

OR

Is Topic system an acceptable alternative?  I mean can I have hundreds of topics published and subscribers scattered all other the app in different widgets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use directly dojo dmodel library as stated in their documentation:

> Once we have the property object, we can access meta-data, watch, and
>   modify this property. [Source](https://github.com/SitePen/dmodel).

```
nameProperty.observe(function(newValue){
    // called with original value and each change
});
nameProperty.put("Mark");
```

You can use `dojo/topic` to implement [Publish/Subscribe Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh201955.aspx) in JavaScript which basically allow you to have a centralized hub for publishing and subscribing to global messages (which could work across your AMD modules).

So you could use `.observe()` from `dmodel` to watch your properties and when a property is changed you can inform other part of your app (module) using `dojo/topic`.